# How to get types from variadic parameter pack in generic lambda?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, variadic-templates, generic-lambda

I'm trying to write a function that will return a [generic lambda](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp14-language#generic-lambdas) with variadic arguments, where the lambda checks that one of the arguments is equal to a specific value. Here's (roughly) what I'm trying to do:

```
template <int Index, typename TValue>
inline auto arg_eq(const TValue& value) 
{
    return [value] (auto... args) -> bool {
        return (std::get<Index>(std::tuple</* ??? */>(args...)) == value);
    };
}
```

I'm not sure what to put in the `std::tuple</* ??? */>` template argument. I've tried `decltype(args)`, `decltype(args...)`, `auto`, `auto...`, and a few other things, but I keep getting compiler errors. Is this even possible?

The non-generic equivalent would be something like:

```
template <int Index, typename TValue, typename... TArgs>
inline auto arg_eq(const TValue& value)
{
    return [value] (TArgs... args) -> bool {
        return (std::get<Index>(std::tuple<TArgs...>(args...)) == value);
    };
}
```

This works fine, but the returned lambda isn't generic - it doesn't work with any arbitrary parameter pack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm not sure what to put in the std::tuple template argument. I've tried decltype(args), decltype(args...), auto, auto..., and a few other things, but I keep getting compiler errors.

Try with

```
std::tuple<decltype(args)...>
```

The full function

```
template <int Index, typename TValue>
inline auto arg_eq(const TValue& value) 
{
    return [value] (auto... args) -> bool {
        return (std::get<Index>(std::tuple<decltype(args)...>(args...)) 
                 == value);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You could avoid mentioning the types by simply using [std::make_tuple](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple):

```
template <int Index, typename TValue>
auto arg_eq(const TValue& value) 
{
    return [value] (auto... args) -> bool {
        return (std::get<Index>(std::make_tuple(args...)) == value);
    };
}
```